# Type two statements. The first reads user input into person_name. The second reads user input into person_age. Use the int() function to convert

Tags: python

[problem being presented]
[image: 1]

I have tried every which way that I have learned, and nothing seems to be giving me the answer that zybooks wants. It wants me to use the int() function, but every time I run it, it pops up with the error code that I cannot use a built-in function. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: _I have tried every which way that I have learned_ Show us the code you tried, and show us the error message.

Comment: Also, if you're not able to use "a built in function", then I don't see how you can do _anything_.

Comment: it says convert string to int so you can use type conversion

Comment: Also show the error.

Answer (score 1):

Type two statements. The first reads user input into person_name. The second reads user input into person_age. Use the int() function to convert person_age into an integer. Below is a sample output for the given program if the user's input is: Amy 4
In 5 years Amy will be 9
Note: Do not write a prompt for the input values, use the format: variable_name = input()

person_name = input()

age = input()

person_age = int(age)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j2Rq.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of code that should work.

```
name = input('Enter Name: ')
age  = int(input('Enter Age: '))

print('Name entered: ', name, 'Age entered: ', age)
```

I just tried it out and it stored the name and age.  Perhaps you weren't wrapping the age "input" inside the "int" function.

See if that helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

person_name = input('')

person_age  = int(input(''))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the '' blanks because zyBooks has technically added the inputs.
So, we don't have to input 'Amy' and '4' otherwise it will keep giving you an error message.

person_name = input('')
person_age = int(input(''))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).